# php regex to change paths

Tags: php, regex

I am new to PHP and regex hence need help using it to che some image paths.

My CMS generates image paths like this:

```
<img src="http://localhost/test/images/normal/ima1.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="ima1">
```

I am using PHP and i have a variable `$size` and I want that if `$size = 'small'` then the path should be

```
<img src="http://localhost/test/images/small/ima1.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="ima1">
```

and if if `$size = 'medium'` then the path should be

```
<img src="http://localhost/test/images/medium/ima1.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="ima1">
```

These links are dynamically generated by my CMS hence I am looking for the PHP code which will replace the flder name in these links after the page is rendered.

All I want to replace is the word between `images/` and the `/` after the replacing word.

Comment: Modify your CMS' relevant code/plugin code, don't replace stuff after the page has loaded.

Comment: You have not posted any code that does the regular expression matching/replacement, how should we know to what to apply it to? To the whole page? So please post your code otherwise your question is too broad I'd say.

Comment: @hakre I dont kow the regex code and that is what I am asking for here.

Comment: You don't need regex for your problem, the string prefix that you want to replace if of a fixed size.

Comment: @hakre I am sorry but I a not understanding your suggestion. I am a new programmer an just started to learn PHP hence requesting you if you can provide the code with corret sytax and instructions as to how can I mpliment it in my code mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry your question is of too specific nature while it has too less information that I would be able to decipher and answer it in a way I would be confident with.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$blabla = preg_replace( "/images\/[a-zA-Z]\//" , "images\/" . $size . "\/" , $sourceCode );`

Now, `$blabla` is a random name. You could change it to whatever you want. 
`$sourceCode` is also a name. You need to replace it with the string you want to replace.
E.g. `$sourceCode = "<img src=\"http://localhost/test/images/small/ima1.jpg\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\" alt=\"ima1\">"`.

The syntax of the function preg_replace is as follows: [preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject )](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php).

It means: $pattern - the pattern you would like to replace in you string (our case $sourceCode), like `"/images\/[a-zA-Z]\//"`. You could read about regexp syntax [here](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php).

$replacement - the text you want to put instead of the pattern. Since we are looking for everything that looks like "images/SOME_TEXT/" - we are replacing the whole pattern. To fill the `src` attribute correctly, we make our replacement as `"image/" . $size . "/"`.
If we wrote a single $size as the replacement, we would get our $blalba as `"<img src=\"http://localhost/test/smallima1.jpg\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\" alt=\"ima1\">"`.
Notice the `smallima1.jpg` (that's in case `$size = "small"`).

P.S. Notice the backslashes before every `"`. They are preventing from the php parser to think it's the end of the string input. E.g. `$name = "The "Batman"";` will return error, while `$name = "The \"Batman\"";` will assign `The "Batman"` to the variable `$name`. 
They are neccessary, if you assign a string that contains quotes to a variable.

Comment: Since the OP has specified that he is "new" to regular expressions, an explanation should be included...

Comment: Ok it didnt work. I copy pasted your code in my `index.php` file and Iget an error `Undefined variable: courseCode`. Can you please explain why you have used these 2 variables `$blabla` and `$courceCode`? and do I need to use them somewhere in my code. Is copy-pasting your above code sufficent ar do I have to do something else too.

Comment: This is how the htlis generated by y CMS.`<div class"content">
<p><img src="cdn/images/normal/1.jpg" width="500" height="375">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus interdum porta tellus vitae molestie. Nullam eu lorem orci, quis pulvinar urna. Sed dictum viverra erat, accumsan euismod dolor pretium pulvinar. Vestibulum nec arcu non nibh luctus lacinia ac vel lacus. </p>`

Answer (score 0):

Providing that all your images are under the same path, I recommend you leave regular expressions alone (this time), and opt for a much easier `explode()` method.

Using the PHP `explode()` function you can split a string into an array using a delimiter.

```
$str = 'http://localhost/test/images/small/ima1.jpg'; 
$arr = explode('/',$str);
```

This should give you something like this -

```
Array 
(
    [0] => http:
    [1] =>
    [2] => localhost
    [3] => test
    [4] => images
    [5] => small
    [6] => ima1.jpg
) 

// remove the protocol specification and the empty element.
// You'll see that the `explode()` function actually removes the slashes 
// (including the two at the beginning of the URL in the protocol specification),
// you'll have to return them once you have finished.
array_shift($arr);
array_shift($arr);
```

Now you are left with -

```
Array 
(
    [0] => localhost
    [1] => test
    [2] => images
    [3] => small
    [4] => ima1.jpg
)
```

Providing the URL's are the same for all images, you can simply replace the fourth element (`$arr[3]`) with the relevant size and then reassemble your URL using the `implode()` function.

```
array_unshift($arr,'/'); // adds an element to the beginning of an array
array_unshift($arr,'http:');
$finalURL = implode('/',$arr);
```

---

Relevant documentation -

- `explode()` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
- `implode()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php
- `array_shift()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php
- `array_unshift()` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php

Comment: @Lix, I think doing a regex replace, or even using `parse_url()` is a better way of doing it rather than doing numerous array operations.

Comment: Yes - indeed there was a syntax error there.  The array needs to appear before the elements that you are prepending. `array_unshift($arr,'/');`.  I have updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: Now I'm embarrassed :P  Yea - sorry for that too.  All these things are written in the documentation links I gave - you should also give them a look (like me ;)

Comment: ok here is the final code but, no errors but it does not work. `$str = 'http://localhost/test/images/normal/1.jpg'; 
$arr = explode('/',$str);

array_shift($arr);
array_shift($arr);

$arr[3] = ($layout);

array_unshift($arr,'/'); 
array_unshift($arr,'http:');
$finalURL = implode('/',$arr);`

echo $layout;` it does not change the URL.

Comment: Well what is your value of `$layout`?  Also you don't need those brackets around it...

Answer (score 0):

My question for you is why do you want to `replace` ??? I if your site is properly structured you don't need replace

I expect something like this

```
$sizes = array("normal"=>array(500,500),
        "small"=>array(100,100),
        "medium"=>array(300,200));


$selected = "small"  ;
$imageHost= "http://localhost/test/images" ;
$imagePath = "/public_html/test/images" ;
$imageName = "ima1.jpg" ;
$tag = "<img src=\"{$imageHost}/%s/$imageName\" width=\"%d\" height=\"%s\" alt=\"ima1\">";
```

Simple Demo to output all sizes

```
echo "<pre>" ;
foreach($sizes as $size => $dim){

    if(!file_exists($imagePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $selected . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .  $imageName))
    {
        // Am sure you want to either create the image or copu the thumn here 
    }
    echo printf($tag,$size,$dim[0],$dim[1]) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
<img src="http://localhost/test/images/normal/ima1.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="ima1">
<img src="http://localhost/test/images/small/ima1.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="ima1">
<img src="http://localhost/test/images/medium/ima1.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="ima1">
```

Comment: Why do I want to replace the paths? because my NORMAL image s 18KB, my MEDIUM image is 12KB an my SMALL image is 6KB and like tis  have about 20 images on th page and imaginfe the amount of page speed I will increase by replacing it wih a smaller image for small and slow devices. Also the images are croped to higligh only the important portion for smaller devics hence changing the dimentions will not resolve my issue.